# How to send TOEFL score to a particular department?

Tags: graduate-admissions, toefl

I am applying to the Ph.D. program in McGill. As it says at the end of this [page](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/students/graduate/application/), we have to send our TOEFL score to the department. But in the ETS website I cannot find the department, I can only find the institute.

What to do ?

Comment: Have you tried asking the department at McGill?

Answer (score 2):

The website lists the following:

> Appropriate exam results must be submitted directly from the TOEFL (Test of English as a Foreign Language) or directly from the IELTS Office (International English Language Testing Systems) to McGilll University (Code 0935), Department code for: general Math (072) and Statistics (059).  An institutional version of the TOEFL is not acceptable.

If those codes are not available, I would reach out to the department for advice on how to proceed via email. Screenshot the list of departments on the website to show that it is not listed. Perhaps also CC the testing center/company.